# MySQL group by date and convert from unix timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have the following sql table (simplified)

```
ID (int)  title (text)            date (int)
--------------------------------------------
1         Hello World             1378148920
2         Hello World2            1378182183
3         Hello World3            1378129838
4         Hello World4            1378146160
5         Hello World5            1378138038
....
```

The table has thousands of entries.

I wan't to ask you if it is possible to build a SQL query that groups all the posts by date but only as day.

So at the end I wan't to build a graph like this (for the last 5 days):

```
02.09.2013: 13 posts
01.09.2013: 14 posts
```

NOTE: the timestamp aren't real (they are all from today)

Comment: in short: yes its possible you can format date and use group by

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [from-unixtime()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`, '%d.%m.%Y') as ndate,
       count(id) as post_count
from your_table
group by ndate
```

Comment: Thanky you. I tried you solution and I think it works, but if i try to set ORDER BY ndate DESC LIMIT 0 , 5 the results aren't ordered.

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I had to order it after post_date, not ndate, of course