# How can I count entries for each day of the last 7 days in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table in my database:

```
id  |  start_date  |  text
--------------------------
1   |  1446109949  |   hi
2   |  1446109436  |   gsdgsd
3   |  1446103439  |   hfdhf
4   |  1446325345  |   bvbcv
5   |  1446105754  |   fdsfsd
6   |  1446266344  |   fdsfds
7   |  1446643646  |   hfdhfd
etc.
```

Basically it contains a lot of records, each of them contains its own timestamp.
I try to make a query that returns me the number of records for each of the last 7 days. So when user runs it today, it will show him that there are 3 texts assigned for yesterday, 5 for two days ago, and so on until 7 days ago.

Since I don't know too much about grouping in SQL, I assume this query will begin as `SELECT Count(id) from USER_TEXT` but I don't know how to proceed from that. Could you help me with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want something like the following result :

```
date       |  num_texts
-------------------------
2015-10-28 | 3
2015-10-27 | 1
2015-10-26 | 8
etc.
```

then look at the query at [MySQL group by date and convert from unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593539/mysql-group-by-date-and-convert-from-unix-timestamp)

However, if you would like the result to be something like :

```
days_ago   |  num_texts
-------------------------
0          | 6
1          | 3
2          | 1
3          | 8
etc.
```

then you can use the following query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT DATEDIFF(now(), FROM_UNIXTIME(start_date)) AS days_ago, COUNT(id) AS num_texts 
      FROM USER_TEXT 
      GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(start_date))) AS temp 
WHERE days_ago <= 7
```